# RMarkdown Officedown: Table (flextable) caption prefix not working anymore

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

For some reason I cannot generate prefixes for table captions (including separator) in officedown generated word documents anymore.

This is my YAML:

```
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    tables:
      caption:
        style: Table Caption
        pre: 'Table '
        sep: ': '
---
```

And this is my flextable code chunk:

````
```{r, tab.cap = "My table"}
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  flextable()
``
````

The output table caption is "My table", but I was expecting "Table 1: My table". Just some months ago it was still working.

Answer (score 1):

We had to change how captions are working for compatibility with quarto. For now an id is mandatory.

````
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    tables:
      caption:
        style: Table Caption
        pre: 'Table '
        sep: ': '
---

```{r, tab.id = "any_id", tab.cap = "My table"}
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  flextable()
```
````